# Return the list is empty python

Tags: python

I'm a little confused how to return a list in python, the code below is returning an empty list. I do not quite understand how the functions work.

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context, ntforg
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import builder

import threading
import collections
import time

MibObject = collections.namedtuple('MibObject', ['mibName',
                                   'objectType', 'valueFunc'])

list1 = []
class Mib(object):
    """Stores the data we want to serve. 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._test_count = 0
        self._test_get = 10
        self._test_set = 0 

    def getTestDescription(self):
        return "My Description"

    def getTestCount(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self._test_count

    def setTestCount(self, value):
        with self._lock:
            self._test_count = value

    def getTestGet(self):
        return self._test_get

    def getTestSet(self):
        return self._test_set

    def setTestSet(self):
        with self._lock:
            self._test_set = value

class Main (list):

    def doObjects(self, list1):

        mib = Mib()
        self.list1.append(MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription))
        self.list1.append(MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount))

        return self.list1

    print list1
```

For what reason the function is returning an empty list?

Comment: Which function are you talking about?

Comment: You're assigning an empty list to `list1`, so `list1` will refer to an empty list. You never assign another value to it.

Comment: ^ is correct, the list1 inside of `class Main` refers only to a local variable of list1, then tries to update a non existent class variable `self.list1`, then you try print the global list1

Comment: when I do {self.list1.append} , I'm not adding an element in the list?

Comment: self.list1 does not exist and your function is never called!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, your code shoud do nothing.

I guess you are calling `Main()` in some way. But the function `doObjects` is never called. Moreover, you may have forgotten to add `self.list1 = list1` in your function definition

The good way to do this could be first to add to your script at the end:

```
M = Main()
return_list = M.doObjects()
print return list
```

And your Main function could/should be:

```
class Main(list):

    def doObjects(self, list1):
        self.list1 = list1
        mib = Mib()
        self.list1.append(MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testDescription', mib.getTestDescription))
        self.list1.append(MibObject('MY-MIB', 'testCount', mib.getTestCount))
        return self.list1
```

But still, `list1` is defined outside `Main`, I guess you should rethink/redesign your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with variable scope. You've actually got three different objects named `list1`:

- The global variable `list1 = []` which you assign before the `Mib` class.
- The `list1` attribute of the `Main` class. This actually refers to a nonexistent attribute, as you never set it anywhere. Thus calling `doObjects` would raise an `AttributeError`.
- Also, `doObjects` takes an argument named `list1` which is never used anywhere.

Now, your print statement in the body of the `Main` class is executed when the class is created, and prints the global `list1` variable, which is the only one of the three visible from that scope. As you never append anything to that list, it is of course empty.

As a side note, you have all kinds of other issues in your code and should probably spend some time learning the python basics. Your `Main` class has no reason to have `list` as a parent class. You never create an instance of your classes. Actually, your code doesn't even do anything except declaring two classes and a `namedtuple` class...

Comment: I cannot agree more with your analysis..